# Puppeteer is detected on ubuntu server but not locally

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

so I have a puppeteer script to watch TikTok live streams and when I run it locally it works as expected, but in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server the page loads for the live stream, but the live stream never starts and it requires me to log in, which doesn't have locally either. Any ideas to bypass that detection?

Settings

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const { Cluster } = require("puppeteer-cluster");

// Use stealth plugin to bypass bot detection
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
const AnonymizeUA = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua");
const AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker');

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
puppeteer.use(AnonymizeUA());
puppeteer.use(AdblockerPlugin({ blockTrackers: true }));


(async () => {
  const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
    maxConcurrency: 60000,
    timeout: 86400000,
    puppeteer: puppeteer,
    retryLimit: 10,
    retryDelay: 1000,
    puppeteerOptions: {
      headless: true,
      timeout: 120000, //360000
      args: [
        "--start-maximized",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas",
        "--no-first-run",
        "--no-zygote",
        "--disable-gpu",
      ],
      executablePath: "/snap/bin/chromium",
      defaultViewport: null,
    },
  });
```

Even when I install GUI on the machine, and visit the live stream manually I still cant view it, so it has something to do with the server getting detected as a server maybe?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried adding user-agent?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that